# tcp lost packet python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcp

i am using tcp socket for forwarding data (as class with type of request, and data) between server and client. When i send 6 object of order from client, the server get only 5 object of order, 1 is lost, but tcp is reliable protocol... (sometimes the server get 6 but usually get 5) my question is why an object lost in forwarding by tcp?

**Here's the client code**

```
PORT = 3000
SIZE = 4096
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
soc = None
ing_map = None


def connect_to_client():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    global soc
    soc = s


def send_object(data):
    if soc is None:
        raise NotImplementedError  # There is no connection
    else:
        # make data as bytes
        msg = pickle.dumps(data)
        msg = bytes(f"{len(msg):<{HEADERSIZE}}", 'utf-8') + msg
        print(sys.getsizeof(msg))
        soc.send(msg)


def get_object(req):
    if soc is None:
        raise NotImplementedError  # There is no connection
    else:
        # unpickle the data
        send_object(req)
        if soc is None:
            raise NotImplementedError  # There is no connection
        else:
            # unpickle the data
            data = b''
            while True:
                part = soc.recv(SIZE)
                data += part
                if len(part) < SIZE:
                    break
            full_msg = data
            try:
                data = pickle.loads(full_msg[HEADERSIZE:])
            except EOFError:
                data = None
            return data


def send_order(order):
    if order is not None:
        send_object(Soc_request(Request.P_ORDER,order))


def main():

    global ing_map
    connect_to_client()
    ing_map = get_object(Soc_request(Request.G_ING_MAP, None))

    #send order
    burger = Burger(ing_map)
    salad = Salad(ing_map)
    burger.add_ingredient('ham')
    o1 = Order(Priority.NORMAL)
    o2 = Order(Priority.NORMAL)
    o3 = Order(Priority.VIP)
    o4 = Order(Priority.VIP)
    o5 = Order(Priority.PLUS)
    o6 = Order(Priority.PLUS)
    o1.meals_lst.append(burger)
    o1.meals_lst.append(burger)
    o1.meals_lst.append(burger)
    o3.meals_lst.append(burger)
    send_order(o1)
    send_order(o2)
    send_order(o3)
    send_order(o4)
    send_order(o5)
    send_order(o6)

    soc.close()
```

**Here's the server code**

```
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 3000
SIZE = 1000
HEADERSIZE = 10
WORKERS = 2

conn = None
addr = None
soc = None
order_m = None


def create_connection():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    global conn, addr
    global soc
    soc = s
    conn, addr = s.accept()


def send_object(data):
    if soc is None:
        raise NotImplementedError  # There is no connection
    else:
# make data as bytes
        global conn
        msg = pickle.dumps(data)
        msg = bytes(f"{len(msg):<{HEADERSIZE}}", 'utf-8') + msg
        conn.send(msg)


def get_object():
    global conn
    if conn is None:
        raise NotImplementedError  # There is no connection
    else:
        # unpickle the data
        data = b''
        while True:
            part = conn.recv(SIZE)
            data += part
            if len(part) < SIZE:
                break
        full_msg = data
        try:
            data = pickle.loads(full_msg[HEADERSIZE:])
        except EOFError:
            data = None
        return data


def main():
    create_connection()
    # Initialize objects
    global order_m
    ing_map = Ingredient_map()
    order_m = OrderManager()

    while True:
        msg = get_object()
        if msg is None:
            pass
        elif msg.req == Request.G_ING_MAP:  # get ingredient map
            send_object(ing_map.instance.map)
        elif msg.req == Request.P_ORDER:
            order_m.add_order(msg.data)
            print(msg.data)

    # end while
    soc.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output of the server is 
order 0
order 1
order 3
order 4
order 5
**but order 2 lost!**
why? what should i fix that all the orders will arrive ?
Request is an enum for request type.

Comment: This is not a reproducible example. You are calling classes and functions that are not defined or imported in your example. Please provide a minimal reproducible example and we will do our best to help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: you can see the whole code in https://github.com/Ofekroz10/Restaurant
class back is the server, class main is the client
The other code is not necessary, its no matter if i send order object or cat object, the problem is that i send 6 object from client and server get only 5

Comment: This code is strikingly similar to the code [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60404552/tcp-socket-lost-packets#comment106864974_60404552). Are these related?

Comment: Can you narrow the problem down at least somewhat? That's a ton of code to go through, no?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi What question is that? It looks like it's been deleted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TCP socket python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60411328/tcp-socket-python)

Answer (score 0):

Let's visualize the 6 pickled objects on their way from the client to the server:

```
server <- 1112222233334445555566 <- client
```

A TCP connection is one stream of data. There are no boundaries. The server has to split the data to individual parts and unpickle each part:

```
111 22222 3333 444 55555 66
```

In order to be able to do that, you must introduce some high level structure to the data. I can't run your code, but I don't see anything like that there. Instead the server just reads into a fixed size buffer. The reality is little bit complicated, but I think this is sometimes happening:

```
1112 2222 3333 4445 5555 66
```

The objects 1, 3, 4 and 6 were transferred in one piece, but 2 and 5 were divided into two parts and these parts cannot be separately unpickled.

I think you need to put the length of the pickled data to the header. Then the server should first read the header (fixed size), extract the length and then read and unpickle as many following bytes (not less, not more).

Also this fragment:

```
    try:
        data = pickle.loads(full_msg[HEADERSIZE:])
    except EOFError:
        data = None
```

hides errors. Do not blame TCP for losing packets when you silently discard data.

Comment: okay, but how i send the length of the object in the header and extract the length? can you show me code for example please? thank you

Comment: @ofekRozenkrantz Here at StackOverflow we answer questions. I will not write the code you are asking for. IMHO it is trivial compared to the complexity of the code posted by you.

Answer (score 0):

As @VPfB mentioned, you are sending the header size but never parsing the size. You really should restructure your code, however, here is a working example using your code.

In your client code, change your `get_object` function to this.

```
def get_object(req):
    if soc is None:
        raise NotImplementedError  # There is no connection
    else:
        # unpickle the data
        send_object(req)
        if soc is None:
            raise NotImplementedError  # There is no connection
        else:
            # unpickle the data
            # this initial recv only receives the header length
            length = int(soc.recv(HEADERSIZE).decode('utf-8'))

            data = b''
            while True:
                # here we receive a minimum of the standard recv size 
                # and the diff between your already received data
                # and the full length, whichever is smaller
                part = soc.recv(min(SIZE, length - len(data)))
                data += part
                # if the length that was specifed in the header has been received
                # we know we have everything
                if length == len(data):
                    break
            full_msg = data
            try:
                data = pickle.loads(full_msg)
            except EOFError:
                data = None
            return data
```

Now we'll make almost identical changes in your server code.

```
def get_object():
    global conn
    if conn is None:
        raise NotImplementedError  # There is no connection
    else:
        # unpickle the data
        # the only difference here is
        # when we receive nothing, we know it's time to wait for another connect
        length = conn.recv(HEADERSIZE).decode('utf-8')

        if len(length):
            length = int(length)

            data = b''
            while True:
                part = conn.recv(min(SIZE, length - len(data)))
                data += part
                if length == len(data):
                    break
            full_msg = data
            try:
                data = pickle.loads(full_msg)
            except EOFError:
                data = None
            return data
        else:
            # wait for another connection
            conn, addr = soc.accept()
```

In reality a server typically behaves like this:

```
# do this forever
while True:
    # wait for an incoming connection
    conn, addr = soc.accept()

    # get the length of the data the connection is sending
    length = int(soc.recv(HEADERSIZE).decode('utf-8'))

    # get the data
    data = b''
    while True:
        part = soc.recv(min(SIZE, length - len(data)))
        data += part

        if length == len(data):
            break

     # do some stuff with the data
```

The difference is we wait for a fresh connection after each object received. This gives other clients attempting to connect a turn as well.